# Error de OpenSSL usando composer en ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, composer

Cuando intento usar cualquier comando composer, lanza este error:

```
In RemoteFilesystem.php line 515:

The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL  
operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:                       
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number             
Failed to enable crypto                                                      
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Por la investigación que hice, este error se debe a la configuración del proxy(ya que yo uso un proxy para la conexión a internet). Pero comprobe la configuracion y estaba bien. No se que mas podria hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La configuracion necesaria para usar composer a travez de un proxy es la que esta en el fichero /etc/enviroment.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

http_proxy="http://username:password@10.4.1.20:3128"
https_proxy="http://username:password@10.4.1.20:3128"
```